# control Perspective transform in albumentations

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, albumentations

How can I control perspective transform to convert this picture:

normal Image:

[image: normal Image:]

to this image:

[image: Perspective image]

I have label on image and I have to use albumentations for convert label coordinates.

I have tried this code:
`ALM.Perspective(scale=(0.05,0.22),p=1)`
but I change the picture randomly and I can't control it.